# CodeIgniter and RESTful: how to remove backslashes from returned json?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm struggling trying to remove the scaped characters from the json response in my CodeIgniter with [PhilSturgeon REST Server](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver/).

Everything is working OK, but the problem comes with the response, when I access the URL to get the data in json format I get it, but with escaped characters.

Example:

```
http://localhost/revista_servidor/index.php/api/notas/nota/id/1
```

Gives me the next response:

> [{"id":"1","autor":"Prueba autor","titulo":"Comprobaci\u00f3n de t\u00ed\u00edtulo.","subtitulo":"Comprobaci\u00f3n de subt\u00edtulo.","foto1":"http://link.a.foto/foto1","texto1":"Comprobaci\u00f3n de texto 1.\r\n","pauta1":"1","texto2":"Comprobaci\u00f3n de texto 2.\r\n","foto2":"http://link.a.foto/foto2","pauta2":"1","texto3":"Comprobaci\u00f3n de texto 3.","foto3":"http://link.a.foto/foto3","pauta3":"1","texto4":"Comprobaci\u00f3n de texto 4.","texto5":"Comprobaci\u00f3n de texto 5.","texto6":"Comprobaci\u00f3n de texto 6.","datosweb":"http://link.a.pagina.de.datos/","adelanto":"Comprobaci\u00f3n del texto de adelante","nrorevista":"69"}]

It escapes URLs adding a backslash `\` and changing specials characters (`ó` in this example) with: `\u00f3`.

I've tried adding `stripslashes()`but didn't work. 
I checked the response in developers tools and it comes as expected: *Content-Type: application/json*.

How can I fix this encoding problem? I've also checked the configuration files and there seems to be nothing to change for this issue.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction, below is my code:

Controller: **/application/controllers/api/notas.php**

```
    function nota_get() {
    // ID verification.
    if ( !$this->get('id') ) {
        // NO ID.
        $this->response(NULL, 400);
    }

    $nota = $this->Notas_model->get( $this->get('id') );

    if ($nota) {
            stripcslashes($this->response($nota, 200));
    }

    else {
        $this->response(NULL, 404);
    }
}
```

Model: **/application/models/notas_model.php**

```
function get($id = 0) {
    $this->load->database();
    if ( $id ) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where( 'notas', array('id' => $id) );
    }

    else {
        $query = $this->db->get('notas');
    }
    return $query->result();
}
```

I don't know if this matters, but this data will be accessed via javascript in the client side.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just the way JSON works, try json_decode function.
e.g:

```
$json = json_decode($json_string);
$json->autor;
```

Comment: You are right and as I said before this will be accessed via javascript, so I used jQuery `$.get()` and saw the result in console with no escaped characters. Thanks @Bonik!

Comment: when using `JSON.parse()` on an escaped URL, it removes the backslashes, so you don't have to change anything on the PHP code. Try this: `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse('{"path" : "directory\/sub-directory\/filename.ext"}'))` on the console. You'll see that you'll get back the path without the escaped backslashes. So you could use JS to work with the given data from the RESTful codeigniter code with no problems :)

Answer (score -1):

1) You need to be using json_decode() and then urldecode(), instead of stripslashes()

2) Both urldecode() and stripslashes() take a string as an argument, while you are trying to feed into it an object -- which gets "autoreduced" into something that depends on the PHP version... Whatever it is, it's probably not what you are expecting.

In your code:

```
if ($nota) {
        stripcslashes($this->response($nota, 200));
}
```

you'll need a) save the result of decoding to the same or another variable, b) to loop through your object ( $nota ) and unescape the value in each key-value pair.

Try

```
...
$cleanObject = array();

if ($nota) {

    $decodedObject = json_decode($this->response($nota, 200));

    foreach ( $decodedObject as $key => $value ) {

      $cleanObject[$key] = urldecode( $value );

    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($cleanedObject);
echo "</pre>";

// output 
/* 
Array
(
[id] => 1
[autor] => Prueba autor
[titulo] => Comprobación de tíítulo.
[subtitulo] => Comprobación de subtítulo.
[foto1] => http://link.a.foto/foto1
[texto1] => Comprobación de texto 1.

[pauta1] => 1
[texto2] => Comprobación de texto 2.

[foto2] => http://link.a.foto/foto2
[pauta2] => 1
[texto3] => Comprobación de texto 3.
[foto3] => http://link.a.foto/foto3
[pauta3] => 1
[texto4] => Comprobación de texto 4.
[texto5] => Comprobación de texto 5.
[texto6] => Comprobación de texto 6.
[datosweb] => http://link.a.pagina.de.datos/
[adelanto] => Comprobación del texto de adelante
[nrorevista] => 69
)
*/


...
```

Hopefully, this is what you are looking to achieve.

Depending on your further needs, you may have to re-encode the result. Based on javascript you mention, you may then need to convert the result back to JSON:

```
$unescapedAndJSONencodedObject = json_encode( $cleanObject );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @niennte, but it was solved without modifying the php code (well it was modified, I removed the `stripcslashes()` since it was not doing anything). As @Bonik said, json works that way, and when the data is showed in the browser those escaped characters are shown as they should be.

Comment: There is no problem with the PHP code. As I have described in the comment of the accepted answer, JS will read that value with no problem. Altering the PHP code is inconsistent with Codeigniter and it's better leave working things alone, rather than patching them around for no good reason.